# Angular 2 form component valid and pristine properties are returning as undefined

Tags: angular

This is my markup:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<label>Cat Name</label>
<input required #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.catName" name="catName" />
<br>
<div [hidden]="catName.valid || catName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">Cat Name Required</div>
</form>
```

For some reason, the div is always visible.

Using chrome's inspector I can see that the input has 'ng-pristine' applied to it when the page first loads, and if I type a value in, it also gets 'ng-valid'.

For some reason the div is always visible though. I tried debugging it by adding a click event that examined catName and found that `valid` and `pristine` were both `undefined`.

I am basing this on the [angular 2 forms tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).

If I change the [hidden] to `true || catName.valid || catName.pristine` then it does hide so it is evaluating the contents, it's just not working.

There are no console errors.

Comment: I think it should be `[hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"` or `#catName="ngModel"`

Comment: You are correct, I was confused about the way the control was bound. Still not 100% sure why it has to have a `name` and a `#something` that is linked to `ngModel` and the tutorial neglects to inform me, but this has fixed it so many thanks.

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  Mine stays hidden regardless whether it's valid/invalid, pristine/inpristine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State of controls can be known by **ngModel**.

***So in order to get state information about the control, you have to deal with a variable to which ngModel is assgined.***

---

```
<input required #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.catName" name="catName" />
```

*This will give state of control associated with **name variable** only.*

---

*To use **catName**, you should probably change above line to,*

```
<input required #catName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model.catName" name="catName" />
```